# Development of spring boot microservice using spring cloud

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

I am trying to  develop a microservices using spring mvc and spring boot with using spring cloud tools and services. And i am planning to deploy my spring cloud microservices in elastic beanstalk. So I have a doubt in deployment process.

- Whether I need to use any container service for deployment into elastic beanstalk? When I exploring i found that writings about containers in cloud foundry. So i  felt confusion that need I deploy any container services into elastic beanstalk or need to include container service dependency file when developing service??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AWS Elastic Beanstalk(EB) or EC2 Container Service(ECS).

If you want to control your scaling and capacity use ECS, ECS will give you control, as you have to specify the size and number of nodes in the cluster and whether or not auto-scaling should be used.

If you want to focus on the app and not much on DevOps use Elastic Beanstalk.  For Elastic Beanstalk just provide a Dockerfile and EB takes care of scaling your provisioning of number and size of nodes, you basically can forget about the infrastructure with the EB route.